# Наследование ui qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Есть класс

```
namespace Ui {
class Base;
}

class Base : public QWidget 
{
protected:
    Ui::Base* ui;

public:
   explicit Base(QWidget* parent)
        :QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Base) 
   {
        ui.setupUi(this);
   }
}
```

Ну и соответственно где-то в файле `base.ui` описан его интерфейс. Нужно сделать класс, который будет наследовать интерфейс класса `Base` и можно было расширять его в дизайнере.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то никак. base.ui это просто описание расположения виджетов в формате xml. При компиляции утилита uic генерирует код на C++, который размещает виджеты так же как вы разместили их в дизайнере.

Вы можете унаследовать виджет Base с его интерфейсом. Вы можете редактировать и дополнять этот интерфейс руками из кода. Но вы не можете редактировать виджет-наследник в дизайнере.